# Make $\sum_1^n a_k / (\sum_1^n a_k^2 + C)$ diverge as fast as possible under the constraint $\sum_1^\infty a_k=\infty$, $\sum_1^\infty a_k^2<\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Among diverging series $(a_k)$ such that the series of squares, $(a^2_k)$, converges, what is the one (if it exists) that has the ratio $\sum_1^n a_k / (\sum_1^n a_k^2 + C)$ going to infinity the fastest (with $C > 0$ fixed)?

Looking amongst power series, it seems $a_k \sim 1/\sqrt{k}$ is the best, yielding a rate of $\sqrt{k}/\log(k)$ but can this be proved rigorously?

Comment: What do you mean by "maximize the ratio"? In your example the limit of the ratio doesn't exist

Comment: As explained in the main part of the question: making it diverge the fastest. I'll edit

Comment: Note: Your suggestion $1/\sqrt{k}$ doesn't satisfy the constraint $\sum_k a_k^2 < \infty$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\alpha = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k^2 < \infty$. By Cauchy-Schwarz, you have
$$
\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k}{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2 + C} \leq \sqrt{n} \frac{\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2}}{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2 + C} \sim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{\alpha}}{\alpha+C} \cdot \sqrt{n}
$$
so, up to constants, a rate of $\sqrt{n}$ is the best you can achieve. And, by looking at variants of $a_k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{k \log k} f(k)}$ for suitably slowly growing $f(k)$, one can achieve rates arbitrarily close to $\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Thanks Clément. Is $f(k) = (\log(\log (k))^{1/2 + \epsilon}$, $\epsilon >0$ going to 0 what you have in mind ? So that the squared series converge, but $\alpha$ gets arbitrarily big and $\alpha / (\alpha + C)$ is close to 1.

What I'm missing is how that implies tightness, because I have no closed form/lower bound for the LHS for that $f$.

Also, I realized that I don't really care if $\sum_k a_k^2$ covnerges, what matters is that $\sum_k a_k$ diverges.

Comment: @P.Camilleri for the tightness, even there is no closed form you can get good asymptotics via, e.g., a comparison series/integral.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(a_n)$ be such a sequence. Let $\alpha = \sum_{n \geqslant 1} a_n^2 < +\infty$ and for all $n$, $\displaystyle b_n = \frac{\sum_{k = 1}^n a_k}{\sum_{k = 1}^n a_k^2 + C}$. We can actually get better than $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\ln(n)}$ (see third claim and example).

**Claim :** $b_n = \mathrm{O}(\sqrt{n})$. See @Clément C.'s proof using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

**Claim :** We actually have $b_n = \mathrm{o}(\sqrt{n})$. Indeed, let $\varepsilon > 0$. There is a rank $N$ such that $\sqrt{\sum_{n \geqslant N} a_n^2} \leqslant \frac{C}{2}\varepsilon$ by convergence of the remainer of a convergence series toward $0$. It implies that for all $n \geqslant N$,
\begin{align*}
b_n & = \frac{\sum_{k = 1}^n a_k}{\sum_{k = 1}^n a_k^2 + C}\\
& \leqslant \frac{\sum_{k = 1}^{N - 1} a_k}{C} + \frac{\sum_{k = N}^n a_k}{C}\\
& \leqslant \sqrt{N}\frac{\sqrt{\alpha}}{C} + \sqrt{n - N}\frac{\sqrt{\sum_{k = N}^n a_k^2}}{C} \textrm{ using the same trick with Cauchy-Schwarz},\\
& \leqslant \sqrt{N}\frac{\sqrt{\alpha}}{C} + \sqrt{n - N}\frac{1}{C}\frac{C}{2}\varepsilon\\
& \leqslant \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{N}\frac{\sqrt{\alpha}}{C}\\
& \leqslant \varepsilon\sqrt{n} \textrm{ if } n \geqslant N \textrm{ and } n \geqslant \frac{4N\alpha}{C^2\varepsilon^2}.
\end{align*}
The last inequality comes from the fact that when $n \geqslant \frac{4N\alpha}{C^2\varepsilon}$, $\sqrt{N}\frac{\sqrt{\alpha}}{C} \leqslant \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\sqrt{n}$. It proves the claim.

**Claim :** Reciprocally, if $(\varepsilon_n)$ is a decreasing sequence of positive terms such that $\sum_{n \geqslant 1} \frac{\varepsilon_n^2}{n} < +\infty$, then there exists some $(a_n)$ satisfying the wanted conditions such that $b_n \geqslant K\varepsilon_n\sqrt{n}$ for all $n$, for some constant $K > 0$.

Indeed, set for all $n$, $a_n = \varepsilon_n\sqrt{n} - \varepsilon_{n - 1}\sqrt{n - 1}$. We have a telescopic sum so for all $n$, $\sum_{k = 1}^n a_k = \varepsilon_n\sqrt{n} - \varepsilon_0\sqrt{0} = \varepsilon_n\sqrt{n}$. Assuming that $\sum_{n \geqslant 1} a_n = \alpha < +\infty$, we have for all $n$,
$$
b_n = \frac{\sum_{k = 1}^n a_k}{\sum_{k = 1}^n a_k^2 + C} \geqslant \frac{\sum_{k = 1}^n a_k}{\alpha + C} = \frac{1}{\alpha + C}\varepsilon_n\sqrt{n}.
$$
It proves the second point with $K = \frac{1}{\alpha + C}$. All we have left to do is to show that indeed $\sum a_n^2 < +\infty$. We have, for all $n$,
\begin{align*}
a_n^2 & = (\varepsilon_n\sqrt{n} - \varepsilon_{n - 1}\sqrt{n - 1})^2\\
& = \varepsilon_n^2n\left(1 - \frac{\varepsilon_{n - 1}}{\varepsilon_n}\sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{n}}\right)^2\\
& \leqslant \varepsilon_n^2n\left(1 - \sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{n}}\right)^2\\
& \leqslant \frac{\varepsilon_n^2}{n}.
\end{align*}
The first inequality comes from the fact that $\varepsilon_{n - 1} \leqslant \varepsilon_n$ and that $1 - \frac{\varepsilon_{n - 1}}{\varepsilon_n}\sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{n}} \geqslant 0$. The second one comes from the convexity inequality $0 \leqslant 1 - \sqrt{1 - x} \leqslant x$ when $0 \leqslant x \leqslant 1$. We deduce that the series of the $(a_n^2)$ converges.

**Example :** If you take $\delta > 0$ and $\varepsilon_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\ln(n + 1)\ln(\ln(n + e))^{1 + \delta}}}$, which satisfy the hypothesis of the third claim (it is a Bertrand series), then, you obtain, for some positive constant $K$,
$$
b_n \geqslant \frac{K\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{\ln(n + 1)\ln(\ln(n + e))^{1 + \delta}}}.
$$
You can get even closer to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ by adding more imbricated $\ln$ to the denominator for example. However, I think the convergence hypothesis on $(\varepsilon_n)$ can't be removed.